# Custom error 404 page failed to redirect when a link is clicked

Tags: asp.net

Trust your day went well!
I am having a challenge that I have been battling to settle for a long time but could.
Why? Maybe because I don't know the right keywords to use in my search cos to be sincere am so confused.

I have a customized error 404 page that is specified in my web.config as shown below:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/derrors/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/derrors/500.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

While in my codebehind, I have this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Server.ClearError()
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True 'for IIS 7 integrated pipeine
    Response.Status = "404 Not Found"
    Response.StatusCode = 404
End Sub
```

This is working fine. But, there seems to be a problem that I could not solve so I decided to ask other gurus for help.

Now, here is the problem am facing:
On the custom 404.aspx, I have a LinkButton whose click event fire the redirection code as below:

```
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
    Response.RedirectToRoute("welcome")


End Sub
```

So, take for instance the site login page as: example.com/login, and mistakenly, the person typed example.com/logn.
The user will be redirected to **Error 404: Page Not Found** exactly as I wanted. Below is a screenshot.
[image: Screen Shot]

But this LinkButton1 when clicked, will redirect to something like
**example.com/logn?404%3bhttps%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com%3a443%2flogn**

What am I doing wrong here?

Note: am using ASP.Net, .Net Framework 4.5 and Visual Basic programming language

Please kindly help

Comment: Does it work if you remove the code and add `PostBackUrl="..."` to the linkbutton on the page? I take it this is MVC? Can you add the tag and version to your question?

Comment: Thanks. No, I haven't tried PostBackUrl. But I don't like the idea of PostBackUrl as the URL is always redirected to route